# Django Website - TemplateDoesNotExist at /edit/117/

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, forms

I'm using UpdateView to edit data using forms.

After cliking the Edit button a modal is being popped up with a few forms that can be edited and then after I edit and click confirm I get an error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /edit/117/ (or other pk...)

DevOpsWeb/serverlist_form.html
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://devopsweb:8000/edit/117/
Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
DevOpsWeb/serverlist_form.html
```

1. Why do I get this error?
2. Why when I get the modal the information of the PK is blank...?

Does anyone know any of these questions? I'm really stuck :(
Thank you!

view.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from simple_search import search_filter
from django.db.models import Q
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'


    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()



        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            #if not form.cleaned_data['ServerName']:
            #post.servername = " "
            post.save()
            #text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('serverlist')
    args = {'form': form,  'text' : text}
    return render(request, self.template_name,args)


class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    model = serverlist
    #post = serverlist.objetcs.get(server_id=server_id)
    fields = ['ServerName','Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status']
    success_url=reverse_lazy('serverlist')
```

urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from DevOpsWeb.views import HomeView
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostDelete
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostEdit
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='serverlist'),

     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/Delete/
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name="delete_post"),
     url(r'^django_popup_view_field/', include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/edit/
     url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostEdit.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
]
```

forms.py -

```
from django import forms
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ServerName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length = 30,required=False)
    Owner = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required=False)
    Project = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Description = forms.CharField(max_length = 255,required=False)
    IP = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    ILO = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Rack = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Status = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = serverlist
        fields = ('ServerName' ,'Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status',)

class AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget = forms.TextInput
def clean(self, value):
    value = super(AutoCompleteModelChoiceField, self).clean(value)
    return value


class serverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hotel = AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(queryset=serverlist.objects.all())
```

index.html (The part with the edit button)-

```
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server <b>{{ server.ServerName }}</b> </h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
                                                        {% for field in form %}
                                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                {{ field.errors }}
                                                                        <!-- {{ field.label_tag }} -->

                                <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>

                                                {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                        </div>


                                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <h2><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Confirm</button></h2>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <h2><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></h2>
                </div>
                </form>
            </td>
                </div>
        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you have a file `serverlist_form.html` in the templates?

Comment: Nope, I have never had this template...
But the thing is that I'm using a modal which is like a popup.. and then when I click confirm it supposed to redirect to the same page.
My edit used to work before.. I made some changes and since then I have this error..

Comment: Now it's working perfect. Do you know how can I get the data before when I click edit and not blank forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not overriding one of [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) attributes, [`template_name_suffix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.template_name_suffix), [`template_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name) or [`get_templates_names()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names), default template name that your view would be looking is `<model_name>_form.html`. And you don't have that template

Comment: Exactly. I don't have that template, since I'm using the same page and just popup a modal (A small window) and after I press confirm it supposed to take me back to the same page I clicked the button.
What should I add to the views? Which attribute should I override?

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi try to use `template_name = 'index.html'`

Comment: After adding that under UpdateVIew after I click confirm I get to the
devopsweb/edit/117 and it shows the main page successfully but without any data... 
I tried adding -
posts = serverlist.objects.all()
but it still didn't show anything and the homepage is working without any Database entries.. like it's empty..
Maybe I need to have another Get request? Like maybe I should somehow call the get function to get all the Database after the edit?

Comment: Also, Why under PostDelete I didn't need to do template_name?
After delete it redirects me to the home page succesfully

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi because it's just a post method that don't require template, it just sends request and redirects to provided `success_url`

Comment: Oh ok, so now when the edit looks ok and it goes successfuly to /edit/{{pk}} how do I show all the database items after the edit? I want it to redirect to the home page with all the data like the delete does.

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi i suppose your edit proceeds unsuccessfully and hence no redirect to 'serverlist'

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have about 7 forms... and when I have keep one blank form it goes to /edit and when I fill all the forms it goes clean and edit it successfuly! Do you know how I can allow blank forms to be edited?

Comment: Now it's working perfect.
Do you know how can I get the data before when I click edit and not blank forms?

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi i believe that you better ask another question, or search it for yourself, i could've helped you, but it will take quite a time to understand what is currently going on and how your save works.

Comment: I just posted a new question... I would be greatful if you could check it out. 
I'm really stuck with this edit for over a week... no idea how to solve it through google or youtube videos